# Необходимо Решить задачу Коши для обыкновенного дифференциального уравнения, в компиляторе численного решения выдает NAN

Tags: c, численные-методы, nan

Решить задачу Коши для обыкновенного дифференциального уравнения y'= f(x,y) на промежутке [a b, ] методом Рунге – Кутты четвертого
порядка точности:
y'= (2*x -5)/x^2 *y+5
y(a)=b , a=2, b=4
Точное решение задачи:
y(x)=x^2

Код программы

Не могу понять, почему делится на 0

```
#include <math.h>

#include <conio.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define n 100

float f(float, float);

float ya(float);

int main (void)

{

 float a, b, h, x, y[n];

 float m1,m2,m3,m4; // дополнительные переменные

 int k;

 
 a=2; b=4; h=(b-a)/(n-1); 

 y[2]=4;  // начальное условие

 for (k=0; k<n-1; k++) // метод Рунге – Кутты

 {

  x=k*h;

  m1=h*f(x,y[k]);

  m2=h*f(x+h/2,y[k]+m1/2);

  m3=h*f(x+h/2,y[k]+m2/2);

  m4=h*f(x+h,y[k]+m3);

  y[k+1]=y[k]+(m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)/6;

 }

 
 // сравнение с аналитическим решением

 for (k=0; k<n; k++) 

 {

  x=k*h;

  printf("numerical = %5.2f \t\t analytical = %5.2f\n",y[k],ya(x));

 }

 getch();

}


float f(float x, float y) // правая часть

{

 return (2*x-5)/pow(x, 2)*y + 5;  

}


float ya(float x) // аналитическое решение

{

 return pow(x, 2); 

}
```

Comment: Что за ерунда? `y[2]=4;`?? А потом начинаете работать с неинициализированным `y[0]`? Да тут вообще что угодно может получиться! И, кстати, привыкайте сразу работать с `double`, а не `float`.

Comment: Как я поняла ставиться начальное условие из задачки y(a)=b . Строго прошу не судить только первый курс. Даже если я подставляю  y[0]=1;  так все равно NAN

Comment: Чему равно x на первом шаге? А вы на него делите.

Comment: первый 0 и при нем получается расчетная 1 , а дальше увеличивается Х - но вывод NAN          
  0 numerical =  1.00               analytical =  0.00
0.020202numerical =   nan                analytical =  0.00
0.040404numerical =   nan                analytical =  0.00
0.0606061numerical =   nan               analytical =  0.00
0.0808081numerical =   nan               analytical =  0.01
0.10101numerical =   nan                 analytical =  0.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы [делал так](https://ideone.com/FOGIwz), без всяких массивов, и с *правильной инициализацией переменных*. Кстати, у вас не С++, а чистый С.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define n 100

double f(double, double);

double ya(double);

int main(void)
{
    double a = 2, b = 4, h = (b-a)/n, x = a, y = b;

    printf("%7.3lf   %10.6lf    %10.6lf\n",x,y,ya(x));
    while(x < b) // метод Рунге-Кутты
    {

        double m1 = h*f(x,y);
        double m2 = h*f(x+h/2,y+m1/2);
        double m3 = h*f(x+h/2,y+m2/2);
        double m4 = h*f(x+h,y+m3);
        x += h;
        y += (m1 + 2*(m2+m3) + m4)/6;

        printf("%7.3lf   %10.6lf    %10.6lf\n",x,y,ya(x));
    }
}


double f(double x, double y) // правая часть

{
    return (2*x-5)/(x*x)*y+5;
}


double ya(double x) // аналитическое решение
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Comment: Хороший код. Я бы вставил инлайны, но это от компилятора зависит. Хотя кто РК4 использует? :) РКМ5 гораздо лучше, но это уже не в рамках вопроса :)

Comment: Да все заработало ! Спасибо большое ! Буду изучать дальше )))

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Здесь и [второго порядка хватит](https://ideone.com/nB9rkd) :)

Comment: Я сделала щелчек мышкой , но мои ответы пока не публичные ((

Comment: (у меня не открывается, а туннель - только дома) Чем плохи стандартные алгоритмы - их применяют на любых задачах, в том числе на жёстких. Чем хорош РКМ5 - он работает на многих stiff problems. Не на всех, - иногда приходится "плясать" тупым гауссом.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Ну, это отдельная большая тема — какой именно молоток брать в руки для конкретного гвоздя...

Comment: @DYRNEL насколько я помню, принять ответ (птичка) можно при любой репутации.

Comment: @Harrg О, боги!!! Стрелку от птички не отличила))) исправилась

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Кстати, если хочется посмотреть, как можно написать Рунгу-Кутты *профессионально* :), найдите и посмотрите эту [книжицу](https://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-2095-9.html). Это что-то особенного в плане обобщенности...

Comment: Вроде как листал эту книгу. С точки зрения программирования, допускаю, что она хороша. Но методы - базовые, для жестких случаев непригодные, увы.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Она же называется "Современный **С++**", а не "Современные численные методы", правда? :) Что до применимости того или иного метода — то, как любят писать западные авторы, "серебряной пули не существует", и применять что-то сверхустойчивое для получения обычного x^2 смысла не имеет — слишком излишними будут трудозатраты. Грубо говоря, микроскопом гвозди не забивают :), даже если микроскоп имеется готовый, в библиотеке.

Comment: Это-то как раз понятно. Класс для решения подобных задач сделал ещё в 2009: 4 метода, с автоподбором по сложности.